# Rename image on upload

Tags: php, upload

I would like to rename an image when it is uploaded.

The url of the upload page is upload.php?clientID=123456 and I would like to save the image as 123456.jpg

Here is my upload code

```
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Is this possible?

(Newbie)

Comment: The rename needs to occur as part of the path to the final location in `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do i do this? Sorry newbie here

Comment: @user3092953: You can name the file anything you want by setting the `$target_file` variable to whatever you want to name it.  (Or by using some other value in its place.)

Comment: @David - Ah so can I just do this `client_logo/$clientID.jpg`?

Comment: @user3092953: Well, `$clientID` would only expand in a double-quoted string.  You might also want the path to be fully-qualified just to make sure it's in the folder you expect.  But the idea is that the second argument to `move_uploaded_file()` is the name of the file being saved.  You can provide any valid name you want.

Comment: @David - Ahh Ok, could you answer with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already saving the file:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

Just first set `$target_file` to whatever you want the name of the file to be.

```
$target_file = "/some/path/to/a/file.jpg";
```

or

```
$target_file = "/some/path/with/a/$variable.jpg";
```

The `move_uploaded_file()` function is going to save (or at least try to) the file as whatever you name it in the second function parameter.  So just provide the name you want the file to have.

Comment: thanks however the upload fails when i have ...`.php?clientID=XXXX` at the end of my URL? any ideas

Comment: @user3092953: What URL?  How is a URL being used for the file name?  How is the upload failing?  All that URL fragment does is provide a query string key/value pair.  It doesn't prevent a file from being uploaded.

Comment: the page `upload.php` works fine, if i then add ?clientID at the end it fails?

Comment: @user3092953: You have to explain *how* it's failing.  I can't see your computer from here nor can I debug your code for you.  If adding a query string value causes an error then clearly something in the code is trying to use that query string value and is resulting in an error.  Nothing in the code you posted uses a query string value, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: I have added my code to your answer.
As soon as I add a ? to the end of the url I see `there was an error uploading your file` without the ? it works fine

Comment: @user3092953: Why would you add your code to my answer?  If you have additional information regarding your question, add it to your question.

Comment: I am a newbie and dint know that ok. I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The destination path would need to be modified to use the new file name.  Assuming you wanted to store the file in `temp/`, your final call might look like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['control_name']['tmp_name'], 'temp/12345.jpg')
```

Comment: I have tried this however just see the error `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file`

Comment: Make sure php has write access to the final directory (might involve setting chmod).

Answer (score 0):

```
$images_dir = '/www/images/walls/';
$new_file_name = 'WinterIsComing.jpg';

$target_file = $images_dir . $new_file_name;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```